# C compiler for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, c, compiler-construction

I need to know if there is an iPhone C compiler that can be installed on the iPhone. Then I would like to know what parameter I would put in the `system("compile Foo")` function. Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately for your purposes, an app store app is not permitted to launch another process, which would mean that you couldn't use another compiler even if you could install one on the phone.

Comment: Sorry if I sound uncouth: But I don't care. You can still use whatever app you make on your own personal iPhone.

Comment: @thyrgle - what are you saying? iPhone apps are *not able* to launch any other apps - regardless of what you feel you should be able to do.

Comment: @webdestroya: But can't they make system calls? And then can't they launch stuff using command lines? Anyway, its not really an "App" per say, its a program but an app typically has a standard kind of format and extension. I mean it wouldn't be a standard app that a person would typically picture when they think of an iPhone app.

Comment: @thyrgle - No, I don't believe they can (but I am not 100% sure). But "Not being a standard app" doesn't much matter. You are still held to whatever restrictions apple places on iPhone apps, no matter how non-standard it is.

Comment: @webdestroya: Well when I say "Not being a standard app" I mean it doesn't have .ipa extension necessarily, and also, it really just a command-line program. I'm having trouble finding the exact words... It doesn't have a icon either if that helps...

Comment: @thyrgle - Sorry, I am not really an iPhone developer, so I probably can't answer much more. I am just saying that the regular apps that are loaded don't have subsystem access like that (I believe). But I can always be wrong

Comment: Well, without knowing what exactly you mean by "system call" -- i.e., are you referring to calling into the kernel, or a system() like interface? If the latter, no; I'm not 100% sure on the former, but I'm pretty sure your app won't have access to the kernel at that level. That said, in my own apps, I haven't really even looked.

Comment: you can jailbreak but without jailbreaking, no you can't do what you want.